# Interdependent dropdown in flask with auto submit button

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

Interdependent dropdown in flask with auto-submit button..
Assuming below table is from sqlite database I want 3 dropdowns in the following way
Case1-
if Dropdown1 is selected as 'ab' then dropdown 2 must suggest me 'a' and 'b' option, if I select 'a' option in dropdown 2 then dropdown 3 must suggest me 'aa' and 'aaa' as options.
I want to do this in the flask. Not understanding what should I write in main.py file and output.html file.

table from sqlite

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use HTML and JavaScript.

Below is my code for populating value in a second dropdown based on the value selected in the first.

You can customize this further fulfilling your needs.

```js
// Get first dropdown
let firstDropdown = document.getElementById('first_dropdown');

// When a value is selected in the first dropdown
firstDropdown.addEventListener('change', function() {

// Get value chosen by the user
let firstDropdownValue = firstDropdown.options[firstDropdown.selectedIndex].value;

if (firstDropdownValue == 'ab') {

  // Add the values in the second dropdown based on the value selected in the first dropdown
  let secondDropdown = document.getElementById('second_dropdown');
  let option_1 = document.createElement('option');
  option_1.value = 'a';
  option_1.innerHTML = 'a';
  secondDropdown.appendChild(option_1);

  let option_2 = document.createElement('option');
  option_2.value = 'b';
  option_2.innerHTML = 'b';
  secondDropdown.appendChild(option_2);
  }
});

// Get second dropdown
let secondDropdown = document.getElementById('second_dropdown');

// When a value is selected in the first dropdown
secondDropdown.addEventListener('change', function() {

// Get value chosen by the user
let secondDropdownValue = secondDropdown.options[secondDropdown.selectedIndex].value;

if (secondDropdownValue == 'a') {

  // Add the values in the second dropdown based on the value selected in the first dropdown
  let thirdDropdown = document.getElementById('third_dropdown');
  let option_1 = document.createElement('option');
  option_1.value = 'aa';
  option_1.innerHTML = 'aa';
  thirdDropdown.appendChild(option_1);

  let option_2 = document.createElement('option');
  option_2.value = 'aaa';
  option_2.innerHTML = 'aaa';
  thirdDropdown.appendChild(option_2);
  }
});
```

```html
<label for="first_dropdown">First Dropdown</label><br>
<select id='first_dropdown'>
  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose</option>
  <option value="ab">ab</option>
</select>

<br>
<br>
<label for="second_dropdown">Second Dropdown</label><br>
<select id="second_dropdown">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose</option>
</select>

<br>
<br>

<label for="third_dropdown">Third Dropdown</label><br>
<select id="third_dropdown">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose</option>
</select>
```